Select rows without overlap / dynamic 1 hour intervals



time_start
time_end




'2024-01-01 12:30'
'2024-01-01 13:30'


'2024-01-01 12:40'
'2024-01-01 13:40'


'2024-01-01 12:45'
'2024-01-01 13:45'


'2024-01-01 13:36'
'2024-01-01 14:36'


'2024-01-01 13:50'
'2024-01-01 14:50'


'2024-01-01 14:30'
'2024-01-01 15:30'


'2024-01-01 15:35'
'2024-01-01 16:35'


'2024-01-01 16:30'
'2024-01-01 17:30'


'2024-01-01 17:30'
'2024-01-01 18:30'



Every interval is an event-period. I need the first event to be shown and then the second event should be the next event which has a interval that doesn't overlap with the interval of the first event. Then the third event should be the next event that doesn't overlap with the second event and so on.
Expected output:



time_start
time_end




'2024-01-01 12:30'
'2024-01-01 13:30'


'2024-01-01 13:36'
'2024-01-01 14:36'


'2024-01-01 15:35'
'2024-01-01 16:35'


'2024-01-01 17:30'
'2024-01-01 18:30'



I have tried something like this, but it didnt give me the expected output:
WITH Intervalle AS (
    SELECT
        start_time,
        end_time,
        LAG(end_time) OVER (ORDER BY start_time) AS previous_end_time
    FROM
        deine_tabelle
)
SELECT
    start_time,
    end_time
FROM
    Intervalle
WHERE
    previous_end_time IS NULL
    OR start_time >= previous_end_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ORDER BY
    start_time;


Tagging correctly is a fairly fundamental requirement for getting an answer. Personally if OP can't be bothered to correct their tags they get a downvote... which I will reverse if/when they correct it.

I am going to assume MySQL based on the INTERVAL 1 HOUR expression in your posted query.
This is a variation of the gaps-and-islands problem. However, unlike typical gaps-and-islands cases, I do not believe you can use LAG() and LEAD() functions to directly identify the "gaps. This is because the status of each row potentially depends on the results for every prior row, not just the adjacent rows. There are other approaches...
You can use a recursive CTE to select the first row and then repeatedly select the next eligible following row - both using subqueries that select the next "best" row using a combination of ORDER BY and LIMIT 1.
WITH RECURSIVE SelectedIntervals AS (
    SELECT I2.*
    FROM (
        SELECT I.*
        FROM Intervalle I
        ORDER BY I.time_start
        LIMIT 1
    ) I2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT I2.*
    FROM SelectedIntervals S
    , LATERAL (
        SELECT I.time_start, I.time_end
        FROM Intervalle I
        WHERE I.time_start >= S.time_start + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
        ORDER BY I.time_start
        LIMIT 1
    ) I2
)
SELECT *
FROM SelectedIntervals

Results:



time_start
time_end




2024-01-01 12:30:00
2024-01-01 13:30:00


2024-01-01 13:36:00
2024-01-01 14:36:00


2024-01-01 15:35:00
2024-01-01 16:35:00


2024-01-01 17:30:00
2024-01-01 18:30:00



If you wish to use a gaps and islands approach, you can process all of the rows in sequence while tracking the time_start of each "island". A comparison of each time_start with the current island start can be used to identify "gaps". A running sum of the gap flags can be used to number the islands.
WITH RECURSIVE TaggedIntervals AS (
    SELECT
        I2.*,
        1 AS IsGap,
        1 AS Island,
        I2.time_start AS ref_time
    FROM (
        SELECT I.*
        FROM Intervalle I
        ORDER BY I.time_start
        LIMIT 1
    ) I2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        I2.*,
        T.Island + I2.IsGap AS Island,
        CASE WHEN I2.IsGap = 1 THEN I2.time_start ELSE T.ref_time END AS ref_time
    FROM TaggedIntervals T
    , LATERAL (
        SELECT
            I.*,
            CASE WHEN I.time_start >= T.ref_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsGap
        FROM Intervalle I
        WHERE I.time_start > T.time_start
        ORDER BY I.time_start
        LIMIT 1
    ) I2
)
SELECT *
FROM TaggedIntervals

This assumes that there are no duplicate times. If you need to handle such cases, you may need to first number the rows using ROW_NUMBER() and then use that row number to sequence the rows.
Results:



time_start
time_end
IsGap
Island
ref_time




2024-01-01 12:30:00
2024-01-01 13:30:00
1
1
2024-01-01 12:30:00


2024-01-01 12:40:00
2024-01-01 13:40:00
0
1
2024-01-01 12:30:00


2024-01-01 12:45:00
2024-01-01 13:45:00
0
1
2024-01-01 12:30:00


2024-01-01 13:36:00
2024-01-01 14:36:00
1
2
2024-01-01 13:36:00


2024-01-01 13:50:00
2024-01-01 14:50:00
0
2
2024-01-01 13:36:00


2024-01-01 14:30:00
2024-01-01 15:30:00
0
2
2024-01-01 13:36:00


2024-01-01 15:35:00
2024-01-01 16:35:00
1
3
2024-01-01 15:35:00


2024-01-01 16:30:00
2024-01-01 17:30:00
0
3
2024-01-01 15:35:00


2024-01-01 17:30:00
2024-01-01 18:30:00
1
4
2024-01-01 17:30:00



At this point, you can add logic to group by Island and apply whatever aggregation functions needed to achieve your desired results.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Your answer worked perfectly fine, thank you very much!
